# Find button from onclick attribute and click

Tags: html, excel, vba, onclick, intranet

I'm using VBA and stuck on a way to trigger a **Download** button in *HTML PAGE* which inspects below codes:

```
<input onClick="javascript:__dopostback('GridView1','Accountnumber$0')" type="button" value="Download"></input>
```

More than one **Download button** exists on this page and I want to click on the first one.

[image]

In these elements the unique *Attribute* is:

```
"OnClick=javascript:__dopostback('GridView1','Accountnumber$0')"
```

But I don't know how to trigger with below VBA:

```
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 myURL = "Enter your url"
 Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 MyBrowser.Silent = True
 MyBrowser.Navigate myURL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True
 Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Set htmlDoc = MyBrowser.Document
 htmlDoc.all.txtAccNo.Value = ""
 htmlDoc.all.ddlReasons.Value = ""
 htmlDoc.all.txtRequester.Value = "" 
 htmlDoc.all.txtMobNo.Value = ""
 htmlDoc.all.txtLandLine.Value = ""
 htmlDoc.all.txtEmailAdd.Value = ""
 htmlDoc.all.ddlRelation.Value = ""
 htmlDoc.all.button1.Click

 '**OnClick event required here **

 htmlDoc.getElementsByXpath("input[type=""button""]")(0).Click  '<--(Not Working)

 Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
```

Comment: `getElementsByXpath` isn't in my Microsoft HTML Object Library - is it in yours?

Comment: Yes I have, If you don't have _HTML Object Library_ so what about **OnClick event**

Comment: MS office 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly you are calling `getElementsByXPath` but I can't find this method in my Microsoft HTML Object Library (Win10/ Excel 2013).

Perhaps you could try using a CSS selector instead which you can use with the `querySelector` method of the `HTMLDocument` class:

[image]

And then, instead of using:

```
htmlDoc.getElementsByXpath("input[type=""button""]")(0).Click  <--(Not Working)
```

You could try this (untested):

```
Dim strSelector As String
Dim objElement As Object

strSelector = "table#GridView1 > tbody > tr > td > input[onclick=""javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Account_number$0')""]"

Set objElement = htmlDoc.querySelector(strSelector)
If Not objElement Is Nothing Then
    objElement.Click
Else
    MsgBox "Selector did not work!"
End If
```

### Edit

Having had a look at the page source, and in line with the OP statement that:

> More than one Download button exists on this page and I want to click on the first one.

Then we can simplify the select to just this:

```
table#GridView1 > tbody > tr > td > input[onclick]
```

Which translates to find the first `<input>` with an `onclick` attribute in the table body.

So the updated VBA is:

```
Dim strSelector As String
Dim objElement As Object

strSelector = "table#GridView1 > tbody > tr > td > input[onclick]"

Set objElement = htmlDoc.querySelector(strSelector)
If Not objElement Is Nothing Then
    objElement.Click
Else
    MsgBox "Selector did not work!"
End If
```

The selector is tested in Chrome console, so my assumption is that it should work in the VBA in a similar fashion. HTH.

[image]

Comment: Giving error and highlight last instruction `objElement.Click`

Comment: Unfortunately that means the `querySelector` did not work and `objElement` will be `Nothing`. I updated the code to alert if that is the case. Do you have a public URL that I can use so I can test the code?

Comment: Yes, I have public Url:
(http://www.ke.com.pk/complaints-services/duplicate-bill/)

But it has **Captcha** (Characters Image) also.

Comment: Any solution ? @Robin

Comment: That URL you referenced doesn't have a table with an id of `GridView1`... so I can't test. I posted the sample code to offer a solution but unfortunately there is not much more to offer unless we can see the HTML you are working with.

Comment: You will have to copy paste this number **0400003730342** into **Account Number field** then fill **Captcha Field** and then it will display **Table** @Robin

Comment: OK, I got there. I gave an update on the selector. HTH

Comment: Check http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector - which suggests it is implemented since IE11.

Comment: I took another look and the content you are trying to access is in an `<iframe>` with `src="http://www.staging.ke.com.pk:24555/ReBrand/DuplicateBill.aspx"`. I'm getting ***Access denied*** errors everywhere trying to automate the elements in the `<iframe>` so assume there is a cross site scripting problem somewhere. Suggest you need to produce a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and perhaps post another question. Good luck.